# Protect REST URL with same path and different http methods

Tags: rest, shiro

I have a situation that I need some assistance with. I have four REST URL with same path and different http methods

```
/api/users/** GET,POST,PUT,DELETE
```

I want to use Shiro to protoct the PUP, POST, DELETE and keep GET is anonymous. I configured the following URLs  but with out luck

```
/api/users/** =rest[user:update,user:delete,user:create]
/api/users/** =anon
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Maybe you could do something like this:

```
/api/users/**=rest[user]
```

Then, it kind of depends on how you are creating the REST APIs. With a JAX-RS implementation, like Jersey for example, you could do the following:

```
@Path("/api/users")
public class SomeResource {

    @RequiresPermissions("user:read")
    @GET
    public Response getResource() {..}

    @RequiresPermissions("user:create")
    @PUT
    public Response putResource() {..}

    @RequiresPermissions("user:update")
    @POST
    public Response postResource() {..}

    @RequiresPermissions("user:delete")
    @DELETE
    public Response deleteResource() {..}
}
```

This is assuming that you are going with the Annotations based authorization. You could also use the SecurityUtils.getSubject() mechanism.

Comment: Thank you Aritra. the first suggestion /api/users/**=rest[user]  will not work. because. it will make GET needs authentication. I tried using annotation. but it gave no effects. the four resources become not protected

Comment: Did you add the aspectj dependencies for the annotations?